# regex for MAJ or not maj

Tags: php, regex

i got a problem actually writted my array always in lowercase.

```
'bloom' => array(
    'nom' => 'Guigui',
    'instance' => 'Home'),
```

But i use an SQL Request with 'bloom',
have you any regex to implemente to make 'bloom' can be listen in lowercase and uppercase?

simply i would like to make

```
'bloom' => array(
    'nom' => 'Guigui',
    'instance' => 'Home'),
```

Become

```
'(bloom|Bloom|BLoom|BLOom|BLOOm|BLOOM|BlOom|BlOOm|BlOOM|BLoOm|...)' => array(
    'nom' => 'Guigui',
    'instance' => 'Home'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep your array what it like, and just make your query key lowercase.

```
$key = 'BLOOm';

echo $array[strtolower($key)];
```